# Dated Exchange rates and Product Schedules

Tags: opportunity-lineitem, multi-currency

Can someone explain how this works in practice?
Quote the SFDC:

> Dated exchange rates are used for opportunities, opportunity products,
>   opportunity product schedules

How does this look? For example here are two products booked to run in CAD at different time where different exchange rates are in play - so the USD conversion should be different, but it's not. Please explain - thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my testing, it seems the Dated Exchange rate works off the Opportunity Close Date.